# Syntax error, Expecting new line

Tags: python, python-2.7, pydev

I use python 2.7.3 PyDev in Eclipse. From the [porter stemmer source code](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/python.txt)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = PorterStemmer()
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        for f in sys.argv[1:]:
            infile = open(f, 'r')
            while 1:
                output = ''
                word = ''
                line = infile.readline()
                if line == '':
                    break
                for c in line:
                    if c.isalpha():
                        word += c.lower()
                    else:
                        if word:
                            output += p.stem(word, 0,len(word)-1)
                            word = ''
                        output += c.lower()
                print output    # ---- ERROR
            infile.close()
```

I get the error

> Encountered "output" at line 336, column 23. Was expecting one of:
>    ...     "(" ...     "[" ...     ";" ...     "," ...     "."
>   ...     "+" ...     "-" ...     "*" ...     "/" ...     "//" ...
>
>   "<<" ...     ">>" ...     "%" ...     "^" ...     "|" ...     "&" ... 
>   "=" ...     ">" ...     "<" ...     "==" ...     "<=" ...     ">=" ...
>   "!=" ...     "+=" ...     "-=" ...     "*=" ...     "/=" ...     "//="
>   ...     "%=" ...     "&=" ...     "|=" ...     "^=" ...     "<<=" ... 
>   ">>=" ...     "**=" ...     "or" ...     "and" ...     "not" ...
>   "is" ...     "in" ...     "if" ...     ";" ...     "," ...

Comment: Your code is valid Python 2 syntax, maybe Eclipse is using Python 3 grammar. Try running the script from the command-line.

Answer (score 5):

Check what version of the Python grammar you are using (can't recall if it is a global or per-project setting). It looks like your grammar is set for Py3k, in which `print` is now a function instead of a statement.

Edit: I see no reason for that code to not run normally, provided PyDev doesn't get its hands all over it - if you can't run it directly from a python.exe invoked from command line, there may actually be some sneaky bad syntax that I've missed.

Comment: You're welcome. It'd worth using the function syntax for `print` anyway to get into the habit of writing compatible code.

Answer (score 3):

Try, `print` as a function...

```
print(output)
```

Also, check your Eclipse settings to see which python version you are using...

Comment: so I tried this and it works now. In Eclipse under PyDev Interpreter -Python, it is set to Python27

Answer (score 2):

So the problem was that PyDev has a built-in interpreter that it uses in the editor, yet it uses an external interpreter when the code is run. Although I had only python 2.7.3 installed on my computer and that was auto configured by eclipse pydev, the built-in interpreter was set to 3.0. Also the built-in interpreter setting is not available from the options menu under PyDev, but rather it is hidden. When one right clicks the project title in the file explorer and select properties, then there is another interpreter setting. Also, one needs to close all editor windows and reopen them in order to use the updated settings.